# Random distributions in Go with inheritance

Tags: object-oriented, random, go, inheritance, statistics

I am currently discovering Golang, and I try to implement some random variable generation functions similar to R functions.

To avoid code repetition, I'd like to use inheritance, which is quite complex with Go at first sight.

Each variable implements a `x.R()` method, which generate a random value following `x` distribution.

I'd like to implement `x.Rn(n int)`, which simply returns an array of n random values. It is therefore the same for any random variable, as it simply calls `x.R()` n times.

So far, my implementation is as following:

```
// Continuouser Implements a continous law
type Continuouser interface{
    R() float64
    D(value float64) float64
    P(value float64) float64
}
// Continuous A Continuous law
type Continuous struct{
    Continuouser
}
// Rn Generate n draws of a continuous random variable
func (c Continuous) Rn(n int) (res []float64){
    if (n < 0){
        panic(errors.New("n must be positive"))
    }
    res = make([]float64,n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++{
        res[i] = c.R()
    }
    return
}
```

And here is how I implement a law :

```
// NewBern Generate a new variable following a Bern(p) law
func NewBern(p float64) (x *Bern){
    x = &Bern{Discrete{},p,1.-p}
    // Discrete.discreter self reference X
    x.Discrete = Discrete{x}
    return
}

// R Generate a random value following the same Bernouilli distribution as x
func (x Bern) R() int64 {
    var u = NewStdUnif()
    // maybe there is a more idomatic way link int(u.R()<p)
    if u.R() < x.p {
        return 1
    }
    return  0
}
```

So, `x` does embed an anonymous continuous struct, which in turn embeds a reference to `x`, that implements the method `R()`.

You can have access to the full repo [here on GitHub](https://github.com/eric-burel/rgo).

It does work and avoid code redundancy, but is that the idiomatic Golang way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Style comments

- [Don't panic.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#dont-panic) Return the incorrect value of `n` in your error using `fmt.Errorf`.
- [Use gofmt on your code.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#dont-panic) (Have your favorite editor call it on-save.)
- There is no better way to convert a bool to an int than what you have.
- Replace `var u = …` by `u := …`.
- [No need to use named returned parameters in Rn.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#named-result-parameters)

#### On your main question

What you have works, but consider if one caller of your library does:

```
cont := Continuous{}
cont.Rn(42)
```

If you can't guess, try it; it's a good way to learn =) Anyway, you don't want that to happen. So you can do this several ways. Before I'm going into two idiomatic options, let's talk about your interface definitions:

- `Rn` only needs something that implements `R`, so you could probably have an interface only for this. Let's call this interface `Law`.
- Your `Continuouser` should simply be called `Continuous` or `ContinuousLaw` (because it describes what a continuous law does). In its definition, replace the `R() float64` by `Law`.
- Your `Continuous` should be called `MultiDrawer` or something. The only reason you're defining it is because you want to draw multiple values; so name it accordingly.

**Option 1**:

```
func Rn(law Law, n int) []float64
```

It's very simple; what you're saying here is "give me a `Law`, I can give you n random values from it".

**Option 2**:

```
interface MultiDrawer {
    Rn(n int) []float64
}

struct multiDrawer { // unexported: you don't want callers to touch this directly
    Law
}

func NewMultiDrawer(law Law) MultiDrawer {
    return &multiDrawer(law)
}

func (md *multiDrawer) Rn(n int) []float64 {
    // your code using md.R()
}
```

You're saying something similar here: "give me a `Law` and I give you a `MultiDrawer`". It's better if you want to have a concept of a `MultiDrawer` variable that you'll later pass around or reuse.